# To what extent should I be protecting against untrusted/potentially malicious interface implementations?

Tags: java, security, interface

To what extent should I be protecting against untrustworthy interface implementations? That is, instances that are derived by anyone or anything but your own code.

Security and malicious implementations are the primary concerns of course, but I'm also thinking about preventing a bad implementation from making it appear like the error is coming from *my* code. For example, if their `toString()` throws an exception, then my my exception's helpful information

```
throw  new RuntimeException("Something went wrong: Debugging information: [" + interfaceImplementation + "]");
```

will be suppressed (its *type* will be suppressed), and instead will just be a `java.lang.NullPointerException` (for example) without any clues to the actual problem.

I want to prevent the most obvious types of these problems, without littering my code with a try-catch at every interface-call.

What about an "interface-wrapper" which implements the interface itself, but actually does nothing but pass the call back to the actual instance, and try-catch for all possible exceptions *as documented by the function*?

Take this simple interface:

```
public interface UserName  {
   void setName(String s_name);
   String getName();
}
```

Wrap it with this:

```
public class IWUserName implements UserName  {
   private final UserName uni;
   public IWUserName(UserName un_instance)  {
      if(un_instance == null)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("constructor: un_instance");
      }
      uni = un_instance;
   }
   public UserName getUserNameInstance()  {
      return  uni;
   }
   public String setName(String s_name)  {
      RuntimeException rtxUnknown = null;
      try  {
         return  getUserNameInstance().setName(s_name);
      }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
         if(s_name == null)  {
            throw  npx;            //Documented possibility. Just rethrow.
         }
         rtxUnknown = npx;
      }  catch(IllegalArgumentException iax)  {
         if(s_name != null  &&  s_name.length() == 0)  {
            throw  iax;            //Documented possibility. Just rethrow.
         }
         rtxUnknown = iax;
      }  catch(RuntimeException rtx)  {
         rtxUnknown = rtx;
      }
      throw  new RuntimeException("Attempting getUserNameInstance().setName(s_name), s_name=\"" + s_name + "\"", rtxUnknown);
   }
   public String getName()  {
      try  {
         return  getUserNameInstance().getName();
      }  catch(RuntimeException rtx)  {
         //There is NO situation where getName() should throw an exception
         throw  new RuntimeException("Attempting getUserNameInstance().getName()", rtx);
      }
   }
}
```

The `IW*` classes contain a significant amount of code, and obviously must be maintained to remain consistent with interface function's documentation/specifications, but the end result of *using* it is pretty clean:

```
public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
   UserName un = BasicUserName.newInstance();
   IWUserName iwun = new IWUserName(un);

   iwun.setName("Kermit");
   System.out.println(iwun.getName());
}
```

and seems to protect against most everything I'm thinking of.

So how crazy is this IW idea, and if it is crazy, to what extent *would* you protect against this type of thing? Pretending that maintaining this IW code is *not* a pain, are there any other negative consequences in using it?

(I'm not asking for a code-review of the specific design of this IW class. It's just here as an example of how this protection idea, taken to its extreme, might be handled.)

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I am not a design guru but i think this is too much. Even the original java libraries doesn't have such protection. It is not your problem if someone mis-implement your interface. It is their problem.

Comment: Although design decisions are often opinion based, looking at the amount of code you've written to "protect" a trivial interface, I would say: don't. A more sane, but specialized case, might be to separate argument validation and interface implementation. In any case, you should perhaps move the question to "Code review" instead of asking here?

Comment: My real interest is in knowing to what extent should I be protecting against bad implementations. I'm surprised to hear "not at all" so far. I'm not asking for a code review. I am asking, however, if there are any overhead or other negative consequences (beyond having to maintain the code) to actually using something like the IW class. I've updated the original post.